# how can I access the formula in an excel sheet with c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I am parsing thorugh a 2000+ record excel file, and need ot be able to grab the formula itself from the cells and not just the value.  For example, one cell 'Contributions' may be a single number like *1500* or it can be a few numbers *1500+500-200* but I dont want the total, I want the actual formula so I can get the different numbers.

I was just parsing with an oledbconnection and that only seems to get me the total.  How would I go about getting the formula?  Is it possible (I can get it in either XLS or XLSX)?

Thank you.

Comment: all I am getting is incomplete psuedo-answers... anyone have anything a bit more thorough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using OLE Automation, you can access the formula in a cell as follows:

```
formula = worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Formula
```

EDIT:

To use OLE Automation in your C# project, see the following [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084):

Comment: can you explain more about this?

What kind of object is 'worksheet'?  How do I get one :P

Answer (score 1):

A quick google found the following: http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/get-all-formula-from-excel-cell/

Comment: grrrrr... blocked from work, I'll have to check this from home

Answer (score 0):

The xslx is an xml file so it should be easy enough to read. Alternatively you can use third-part components like the one from [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/infragisticsexcel.aspx) that allows you to read xsl-files programmatically and also to access the formulas.